# Is there any scenario where using multithreading on a single core CPU be beneficial?

Tags: multithreading

I know that using multithreading in a single core CPU is possible. But can somebody help me out with a situation or a scenario where it might be useful. I was asked this question in an interview round.

Comment: It is not useful.  Forcing a program to use only one core might be.  It is not a good interview question, perhaps that's not the way they formulated it.

Comment: @HansPassant, Threads were invented many years before multiprocessor systems were a commercial reality. I was writing multi-threaded code for single-processor systems back in the mid 1980s.

Comment: Pfff, I multitasked Z80s before that.  Kids.

Answer (score 1):

Even a machine with single core CPU has I/O devices: network card, hard disks, keyboard, mouse ets. Typical thread mixes computations with I/O operations. When a thread waits for data to be read from devices, it frees CPU, and it can be used by another thread if that another thread exists, which means that multithreading is used.

And when the time spent on I/O operations is negligible, multithreading still can be useful - it can make program more simple, if the task can be naturally parallelized.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are a model of *concurrency*: Using threads enables you to write a program in which multiple, stateful activities each progress at their own pace, independently of one another.

*Parallel processing* is a form of concurrency, and so threads are one way to exploit the resources of a multiprocessor system, but there are other reasons to have concurrent activities in a program.

One classic example is a server that can support arbitrarily many simultaneous, stateful client connections. The server has one thread that awaits new connections, and that thread creates a new *client thread* each time a new connection is accepted.  Each client thread awaits messages from its client, and advances its state accordingly. The state of each client connection can be partially implicit in local variables on the client thread's stack and, on where the thread is executing in the code at any given moment. This design can be much easier to understand than a single thread that must accept input from every client, and *explicitly* store and update the state of each client.

---

A personal preference of mine is to describe every thread I create by first saying what the thread *waits* for:  The server thread in the example above waits for new clients.  Each client thread waits for commands from its client. In a GUI application, the GUI thread waits for keyboard and mouse events.  In a parallel processing scenario, there are worker threads that wait for tasks (computations) to be performed. etc.